# How do I convert string to object type without using eval() in for loop?

Tags: python

**class Testclass:**

```
def change(self, obj):
    if(self.ball):
        self.ball=False
        obj.ball=True
```

**main():**

```
A=Testclass()
B=Testclass()
seq=["AB", "BA", "AB"]
for val in seq:
    obj1, obj2=list(val)    #to split "AB" into A, B
    eval(obj1).change(eval(obj2))
```

.change() method changes object's boolean value to the other object's value. Just for the test.

How can I avoid using eval in this loop? Without eval(), following error appears:
**'str' object has no attribute 'change'**

I'm using python 3.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store the objects in a dict from their "name" to the instances (it's better to explicitly maintain such a mapping instead of falling to the trap of using `locals()` or `globals()`).

```py
A = Testclass()
B = Testclass()

objects = {"A": A, "B": B}
seq = ["AB", "BA", "AB"]

for val in seq:
    obj1, obj2 = list(val)
    objects[obj1].change(objects[obj2])
```

BTW, it's possible to unpack a string directly without `list`:

```py
ob1, obj2 = val
```

Comment: Thanks, I already had dictionary of my objects but didn't think of the [obj1], I tried (obj1] before so but it didn't work so I abandoned it. I will mark your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use tuples instead of strings:

```
A = Testclass()
B = Testclass()
seq=[(A, B), (B, A), (A, B)]
for val in seq:
    obj1, obj2=list(val)    #to split "AB" into A, B
    obj1.change(obj2)
```

Or, combining the unpacking directly with the `for` loop:

```
A = Testclass()
B = Testclass()
seq=[(A, B), (B, A), (A, B)]
for obj1, obj2 in seq:
    obj1.change(obj2)
```

Generally speaking, you'd only use strings if you need to write and read the data to and from a file (or a database or some other external system) or for display on the screen; while it's inside the program, keep things as objects (or numbers etc), don't convert back and forth.

Comment: I had to convert string to object because the seq variable will actually store user input later on.

Comment: All good; user input is exactly where you would indeed use strings (and then carefully parse them because user input can be anything...)